# CSS - Header, Content, Right div, Footer - can't position correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm new there. Currently working on a layout for a website and I'm trying to set up my css rules for the layout.

The idea is tho place in center of the page: Header, Content, Footer. And place Aside (div for banners) next to the Content div.

So far I'm like this: http://goo.gl/8vzX4B (jsfiddle)

The is with Block2 or Blue div. How to attach it right next to Red div that it doesnt affect anything else?

I have tried lots of float combination but nothing worked so far.

Would be thankful for any help!

**CSS:**

```
#block1 {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:900px;
    float:center;
    height:100px;
    background:black;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    }

#container {width:100%;
float:left;}

#block2 {

    width:900px;
    float:right;
    min-width:100px;
    width:200px;
    background:blue;
    height:300px;
    margin-right:20px;
}

#block3 {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:900px;
    float:center;
    background:red;
    min-height:400px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

#block4 {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:900px;
    float:center;
    height:150px;
    background:green;
}
```

Comment: please explain your question. what do you want exactly?

Comment: @lxer I want to get the blue block position like this: http://failiem.lv/down.php?i=ejrjoyy&view (image) Sorry not mentioning it correctly.

Comment: `float: center` isn't a thing, there's only left, right, and none. Setting the containers width to 100% sets it to 100% of the parent element, which is the body.  The divs inside of the container are overflowing outside of the container if the body's width is less than 900px

Comment: @JoeSager I have set width 900px because I don't want to allow div expand unlimited width, that's why I make it like centred. The idea of whole positioning is this: http://failiem.lv/down.php?i=biqtxsi&view (image)

Comment: You should use `flexbox` to build this type of layout... eg: http://jsfiddle.net/girlie_mac/tGPWW/light/

Answer (score 0):

In this case, if all of the widths are fixed, you want to set the containers width to the width of the nav plus the width of the content plus any margins or padding.

So it would be 900px for content, 200px for nav, and 20px for the navs margin = 1120px

```
#container { width:1120px; }
```

Also remove all the `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` rules.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jNVvy/64/

Comment: Your example of jsfiddle still corrupts the layout. This is aproximately what I want, but with side bar on the other side and the center part width of center : http://codegrad.hub.ph/samples/centering-a-fixed-width-webpage-using-auto-margin.jpg

Comment: ...thats the opposite of your first picture. Change the float on the sidebar to left if you want it on the left side. And add `display: inline-block` to the content block (red background)

Comment: Great! Okay, and if I want to put red background in the middle  of the page and not allow it to expand on 100% but on 900px and position blue sidebar to right next to it? Hard to explain, sorry.

Comment: So you want the content to be 100% of the browser width with a maximum width of 900px? Meaning it will be 900px or less?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to achieve.
You should move `block4` (footer?) out of `container`.
Than declare

```
#container { display:table; min-width:900px; /*at least header width */ }
#block2, #block3 { display:table-cell; }
```